# Filter R data set by value but keep rows that come from the same record number

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I have survey results that is organized so that each row is one survey question. That means that one person's survey response might take up 8 rows. I want to keep all of the responses for people who scored a 0 or 1 on the questions: "Provider would recommend" or "Facility would recommend". I know how to filter those scores, but not in a way that would keep all the other rows for those records. What is the best way to write this code.

[image: data]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidyverse solutions:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(record) %>%
  filter(any(question == 'provider' & value %in% 0:1)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   record question      value
#    <int> <fct>         <int>
# 1  26544 provider          1
# 2  26544 confidence        4
# 3  26544 communication     3

dat %>%
  filter(question == 'provider' & value %in% 0:1) %>%
  select(record) %>%
  left_join(dat, by = "record")
# Joining, by = "record"
#   record      question value
# 1  26544      provider     1
# 2  26544    confidence     4
# 3  26544 communication     3
```

Data.table:

(NB: I use `magrittr::%>%` here, normally loaded with `dplyr` above, solely for presentation. I like the pipe-like flow of commands, but it is not difficult to adapt this to a non-`magrittr` flow.)

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
datDT[, .SD[ any(question == 'provider' & value %in% 0:1), ], by = "record" ]
#    record      question value
# 1:  26544      provider     1
# 2:  26544    confidence     4
# 3:  26544 communication     3

datDT[ question == 'provider' & value %in% 0:1, .(record) ] %>%
  datDT[., on = "record" ]
#    record      question value
# 1:  26544      provider     1
# 2:  26544    confidence     4
# 3:  26544 communication     3
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  record = c(26544L, 26544L, 26544L, 655445L, 655445L, 655445L),
  question = rep(c("provider", "confidence", "communication"), times = 2),
  value = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 4L)
)
```

Comment: When I use this code, it includes values that should have been filtered out e.g. "Provider would recommend" with a value of 10

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. If I change the source data with `dat$value[4] <- 10L`, none of this code includes the second record in the results. Show me sample data where this code fails.

Comment: I figured out my mistake. Thanks for the help.